# Currying methods of an interface automatically in C#

Tags: c#, functional-programming

Suppose i have a REST interface that uses WCF to instantiate objects in c#. Suppose this REST interface provides information about **Customers** of a specific business, for example: their name, age, county of residence etc.

The REST interface looks like this:

```
public interface IRestCustomerService
{
  public string CustomerName(int customerId);
  public int CustomerAge(int customerId);
  public string CustomerCountry(int customerId);
  public DateTime CustomerLastPurchaseInStore(int customerId, int storeId);
  ..
  ..
}
```

Now, suppose i have a class:

```
public class Customer
{
  private int customerId;
  private IRestCustomerService restService;

  public Customer(int ctrId, string serviceUrl)
  {
    customerId = ctrId;
    restService = CreateConnection(serviceUrl);
  }
}
```

What i would like is to be able to call the methods defined by the interface IRestCustomerService passing through the customer class, without having to instantiate the customerId parameter; the Customer class should use its member customerId as this parameter.

For example:

```
Customer c = new Customer(1, serverUl);
string name = c.CustomerName();
DateTime lastPurchase = c.CustomerLastPurchaseInStore(5);
..
```

If the rest service interface defines a lot of methods, it is really tedious to write the wrapper functions on the customer class by myself for each method defined by the interface. Is there any way that i can do this automatically?

In functional programming this would be trivial becuase what i want is the curryfied version of the interface. However i cannot see the way to do this in c# without explicitly defining each wrapper method or a new definition of an interface that would require a concrete implementation.

Comment: Not sure if it reailly matches what you're after, but instead of creating an interface for a REST service, could you create extension methods to the Customer class? I've been told previously that putting references to services in your business objects is a bad idea, and that would apply to your example.

Comment: It's not very clear what you actually want. If all implementors of `IRestCustomerService` have a `customerId`, why does the interface require the value at all? If they don't, how would a general solution work? What would it do with implementors of the interface that don't have `customerId`?

Comment: You could declare an extension method on `IRestCustomerService`, which would inspect via reflection the implementing class for an appropriate field to use (caching the result...using of `dynamic` could be useful there), but in your example `customerId` is a private implementation detail; it would be a major design flaw for any code outside that class to even know about the field, never mind use it. And you'd still have to do each method individually.

Comment: Maybe if you'd start with an F# example (i.e. a functional language) and show how _that_ language would do what you want, and explain what syntax you'd like in C# to do the same thing, your question would be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if a WCF client class would tolerate this kind of poking around, but I have seen someone build a "Curry" function for getting lambdas with preloaded arguments:

Check this out: [Currying in C# on Code Rant](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/03/currying-in-c-with-oliver-sturm.html)

Answer (score 0):

First let's suppose you *can* do this manually:

```
CustomerProxy p = new CustomerProxy(customer, service);
var name = p.GetName();
```

and your 'proxy' would only forward the call to the service, passing the right Id:

```
class CustomerProxy 
{ 
    public CustomerProxy(Customer c, RestService svc)
    {
    }

    public string GetName() 
    {
        return svc.GetName(c.Id);
    }
}
```

Now because this is too big a job to do manually, you have two ways around it:

- Use a code generator to generate the boilerplate code for you. Will be much more efficient if you have code-generation tool in your tool-belt. Also less error prone comparing to when done manually.
- Use Dynamic Proxy pattern to do it dynamically at runtime. This will be harder to understand (maybe) but ultimately less code to deal with. Your dynamic proxy wrapper will intercept the calls made to the object at runtime and pass the necessary extra parameter. It will, in fact, work exactly as the manual approach but without having to write or generate the proxy layer. On .NET there's [Windsor DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) library that you can use.